# In this code, where is the attempt to de-reference a null object?

Tags: apex, null-pointer

I've got some simple code and I'm wondering if someone can help me understand why it would result in the "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error? This is part of a custom controller that I'm using for a Visualforce page. Please let me know if I can provide any additional info for clarity.  Thank you!

```
public with sharing class NewBusinessForecastingController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
    public List<SBQQ__Quote__c> q                   {get; set;}
    public List<SBQQ__Quote__c> clonedQuoteList     {get; set;}

    public NewBusinessForecastingController(ApexPages.standardController std) {

        q = [ 
            SELECT 
            SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Quarter_View__c, 
            SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Account.Name,
            SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.CloseDate,
            SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Name,             
            SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Id, 
            Quote_Name__c,
            Name,
            Id, 
            (SELECT 
                SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c,
                Delivery_Start_Date__c,
                Delivery_Frequency__c,
                SBQQ__Product__r.Name,
                Delivery_End_Date__c,
                Line_Description__c,  
                Data_Start_Date__c, 
                Data_End_Date__c,  
                Name,
                Id
                FROM SBQQ__LineItems__r)
                FROM SBQQ__Quote__c 
                    WHERE SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND
                      SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Probability > 0 AND
                      SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.Probability < 96 AND
                      SBQQ__Primary__c = TRUE AND 
                      Id IN (SELECT SBQQ__Quote__c FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c)
                      ORDER BY SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.CloseDate
        ];

        for(SBQQ__Quote__c cloneQuote : q) {
            SBQQ__Quote__c clonedQuote = cloneQuote.clone();
            clonedQuoteList.add(clonedQuote);
        }

    }
```

If I comment out the line that adds each record to the list, I don't encounter the error. The line below is line 41, which is where the fatal error is encountered.

```
clonedQuoteList.add(clonedQuote);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never instantiate your list. When you declare a variable, it is null until some value is assigned.

```
List<Object> someVariable;
system.assertEquals(null, someVariable, 'This variable has not yet been assigned');
```

So make sure you assign a new `List` before trying to add to your collection variable:

```
clonedQuoteList = new List<SBQQ__Quote__c>();
for (SBQQ__Quote__c quote : q)
{
    clonedQuoteList.add(quote.clone());
}
```

Or, you can just clone the list wholesale and skip the `for` loop:

```
clonedQuoteList = q.deepClone();
```

Answer (score 3):

You never initialize the `clonedQuoteList` property, so on line 41 you're trying to call the equivalent of `null.add()`.

You need this line someplace prior to your call to add items to the list.

`clonedQuoteList = new List<SBQQ__Quote__c>();`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've initialized now and got it to work. Really appreciate it.